# Tag number over 30 is not supported

Tags: android, flutter

[image: PREVIEW]

**Error**

Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key key0 from store "C:\mm\omafya": Tag number over 30 is not supported

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For my solution, installed android studio dolphin, and finished my work: https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/2021.3.1.10/android-studio-2021.3.1.10-windows.exe ,

Comment: SOLVED! 
I solved it by using creating new Key because My Key Was Tempered And Corrupted So It was giving error

Comment: It pays to double check your passwords etc, I was back here a few times and I would have bet my life on everything being correct, but in the end it turned out that the CI script that gets these keys wasn't updated and so it was using "" for both fields, and it meant that i got this (very unhelpful) message.. wuups!